# unable to fetch json data - JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm new to python and struggling with below.

The website page URL is https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/equity-derivatives-watch and when we select "Nifty 50 Futures" and upon inspect, we get the api URL as https://www.nseindia.com/api/liveEquity-derivatives?index=nse50_fut.
Now the issue is this json opens up on browser but from python it does not open and gives JSONDecodeError error. I have included right header but still it fails.

One more observation is that when i load this api directly in browser, the python code gets json data once but it does not work there after. One thing i noticed is that a new cookies is set on every page refresh.

Can anyone help me where I'm missing.

Code:

```
    header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
              "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", "accept": "*/*"}

    URL = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/liveEquity-derivatives?index=nse50_fut"
    fut_json = requests.get(URL, headers = header).json()
    print(fut_json)


  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Comment: don't parse directory using `.json()` , check `.status_code`. If it is 200 then only parse. In this case trying your code gives `401` which means unauthorized. So you need to authorize yourself, then only will get the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `cookies` to get the response as `JSON`, as without them you get `Resource not found`.

Here's how:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get("https://www.nseindia.com", headers=headers)
    api_url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/liveEquity-derivatives?index=nse50_fut"
    response = s.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()
    print(response["marketStatus"]["marketStatusMessage"])
```

Output:

```
Market is Closed
```